# kwargs sent over pyAMF channel

Tags: python, syntax, cherrypy, pyamf

I'm using cherrypy server to receive requests over a pyAMF channel from a python client. I started with the mock up below and it works fine:

**Server:**

```
import cherrypy
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.wsgi import WSGIGateway

def echo(*args, **kwargs):
    return (args, kwargs)

class Root(object):
    def index(self):
        return "running"
    index.exposed = True

services = {
   'myService.echo': echo,
}

gateway = WSGIGateway(services, debug=True)

cherrypy.tree.graft(gateway, "/gateway/")
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

**Client:**

```
from pyamf.remoting.client import RemotingService

path = 'http://localhost:8080/gateway/'
gw = RemotingService(path)
service = gw.getService('myService')

print service.echo('one=1, two=3')
```

**Result:**
[[u'one=1, two=3'], {}]

now if instead of:

```
def echo(*args, **kwargs):
    return (args, kwargs)
```

I use:

```
def echo(**kwargs):
    return kwargs
```

and send the same request, I get the following error:

**TypeError: echo() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)**

while at the same time:

```
>>> def f(**kwargs): return kwargs
... 
>>> f(one=1, two=3)
{'two': 3, 'one': 1}
>>>
```

**Question:** Why is this happening? Please share insights

I'm using: python 2.5.2, cherrypy 3.1.2, pyamf 0.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WSGIGateway sets `expose_request=True` which means that the WSGI environ dict is set as the first argument to any service method in that gateway.

This means that echo should be written as:

```
def echo(environ, *args):
    return args
```

PyAMF provides a decorator which allows you to forcibly expose the request even if `expose_request=False`, an example:

```
from pyamf.remoting.gateway import expose_request
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.wsgi import WSGIGateway

@expose_request
def some_service_method(request, *args):
    return ['some', 'thing']

services = {
    'a_service_method': some_service_method
}

gw = WSGIGateway(services, expose_request=False)
```

Hope that clarifies why you are getting the `TypeError` in this case.

You correctly point out that you cannot supply **kwargs directly in a PyAMF client/server call but you can use default named parameters:

```
def update(obj, force=False):
    pass
```

Then you can access the service:

```
from pyamf.remoting.client import RemotingService

path = 'http://localhost:8080/gateway/'
gw = RemotingService(path)
service = gw.getService('myService')

print service.update('foo', True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that with your first echo function, the only way to get the results you do is when it is called this way:

```
echo(u"one=1, two=3")
# in words: one unicode string literal, as a positional arg

# *very* different from:
echo(one=1, two=3) # which seems to be what you expect
```

Because of this, you must write echo to accept positional arguments or change how it is called.

Comment: @Roger Pate: thanks, that clarifies this a bit. If this message prefix is  something pyAMF always adds, I can get rid of it on the server side, but what's the meaning of this 'u'?

Comment: @Roger: if i understand this correctly, if i'm dealing w pyamf, ** is useless, since i'd never get my key value pairs, but instead i'd get u[params]. i should stick to using *args and parse the params myself. True or False?

Comment: That would be Unicode string in ancient versions of Python. In v. 3.1 (probably 2.7 as well) all strings are Unicode.

Comment: Looks to me like you are expecting a single argument (a string)

Comment: Ipthnc is right about `u""` (but 2.x is hardly even close to ancient yet), they are `unicode` (as in the Python type, named after Unicode, the standard) literals; however, 2.7 will maintain backwards compatibility with 2.x, but already in 2.6 there is `__future__.unicode_literals`.

Comment: Dragan: I'm not familiar with pyamf, perhaps someone can provide a better answer (and you should accept it if they do), but I could tell from your well-asked question how echo was being called, and how it differed from what you expected.